# Close node js server when client exits browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server

I am currently looking into writing NodeJS code that:

1. keeps track of the browser connections to the node js server.
2. detects when all browser connections have been closed.
3. shuts down the NodeJS server after a certain amount of time with no connections.
   I'm not too sure how to go about this.

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {    
   request.connection.addListener('close', function () {
      // callback is fired when connection closed (e.g. closing the browser)
   });
}
```

Comment: you need to look into websockets.

Comment: @Kharel do you recommend socket.io ?

Comment: Websockets aren’t needed for this.

Comment: @Joe What would you recommend?

Comment: Generally, server connections from regular HTTP clients are not open long.  You can basically keep a count of incoming connections in the callback you have, and then put an event listener on `request.on('close')` to decrement that counter. Then just have something that checks every so often if the count is 0, and if so, `process.exit`